# error trying to change activities using onClick()

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, onclick

I have the following program that does a calculation based on user input.But when I click the `calc` button which is referenced in `onClick()` nothing happens.As in it doesn't navigate to the result screen.Can somebody shed some light on this as I'm not sure why iit isn't changing intent.

My main class is like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {

    //variables for xml objects
    EditText offsetLength,offsetDepth,ductDepth;
    Button calculate;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            //setting the variables to the xml id's and setting the click listener on the calc button
            offsetLength = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.offLength);
            offsetDepth = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.offDepth);
            ductDepth = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ductDepth);
            calculate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.calc);
            calculate.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);


        }

        //called when button is clicked.
        public void OnClick(View v)
        {
            try {

                String getoffsetlength = offsetLength.getText().toString(); 
                String getoffsetdepth = offsetDepth.getText().toString(); 
                String getductdepth = ductDepth.getText().toString(); 

                double tri1,tri2;
                double marking1,marking2;

                double off1 = Double.parseDouble(getoffsetlength);
                double off2 = Double.parseDouble(getoffsetdepth);
                double off3 = Double.parseDouble(getductdepth)
                        ;
                marking1 = Math.pow(off1,2) + Math.pow(off2,2);
                tri1 = (float)off2/(float)off1;
                tri2 = (float)off3/Math.atan((float)tri1);
                marking2 = (float)off3/Math.atan(tri2);


                Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, CalcResult.class);   
                myIntent.putExtra("number1", marking1);
                myIntent.putExtra("number2", marking2);

                startActivity(myIntent);

                Intent i = new Intent(this,CalcResult.class);


            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                System.out.println("Must enter a numeric value!");
            }

        }
```

Also this is the class where my calculation that should be navigated to:

```
    public class CalcResult extends MainActivity
    {
        EditText result1,result2;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.result);
            result1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mark1);
            result2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mark2);

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            double mark1 = bundle.getDouble("number1");
            double mark2 = bundle.getDouble("number2");  

        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you have `implements OnClickListener` in your class header?

Comment: I have `implements android.view.View.OnClickListener`

Comment: Have you set breakpoints to see if it enters the `onClick()` or not

Comment: I just set one now,waiting for emulator to load....

Comment: if you implements `OnClickListener` in Activity then you will need to override `onClick` method instead of `OnClick`

Comment: also put a `Override` annotation along with @ρяσѕρєяK suggestion and use  `Log` to log info`Log.i("....,"...")` instead of `System.out.println`

Comment: @user2815899 : check this tutorial about how to switch between activities using `onClick()` : http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/android/how-to-switch-between-different-activities-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, CalcResult.class);
```

with

```
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CalcResult.class);
```

Comment: on click listener is not a annonymous inner class so `this` refers to activity context and it should work

Comment: sorry, i think this override method like @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {} .

Comment: so what has that got to do with what you have suggested still isn't annonymous inner class used by op so why would `this` not work

Comment: Also in my CalcResult.class,how would I get the two calculation to appear in my editTexts,mark1 and mark2.Would I set the result1 and result2 to mark1,mark2? Also how would this be implemented as I had trouble with casting.

Comment: @user2815899 you need to convert your double to back to string like `String.valueOf(doublevalue)`

Comment: Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putDouble("key", doubleVal);
yourIntent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(yourIntent); then get this value by:             Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
double result = b.getDouble("key");

Comment: I run the app again but the activity doesn't change.Any ideas?

Comment: Turned out I was calling the incorrect OnClick method().So just changed it to lower case.Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The first error that you have is when setting the Listener on your Button , you should use :

```
calculate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.calc);
            calculate.setOnClickListener(this);//don't cast the listener to OnClickListener
```

instead of :

```
calculate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.calc);
            calculate.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
```

The second error is that the signature of the Overrided method is wrong  , use :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {// notice the "o" in lower case
  //your code
}
```

instead of :

```
public void OnClick(View v) {
//your code
}
```

**NOTE** : check this [**tutorial**](http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/android/how-to-switch-between-different-activities-in-android) about how to switch between activities

Comment: what did you got in the LogCat ?? have you declared the second activity in the Manifest File ?

Comment: @user2815899 have made an entry for the activity in manifest and does it crash. if so post the stack trace and remove the extra line `Intent i = new Intent(this,CalcResult.class)` you have after startActivity